# Render control as ASP not HTML

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm in the need to take an object of WebControls type and generate the ASP.NET markup.

```
Dim lblTest as New Label
lblTest.ID = "lblTest"
lblTest.Text = "Text Here"
lblTest.CssClass = "myClass"
```

Would generate the following string.

```
<asp:Label id="lblTest" runat="server" CssClass="myClass" Text="Text Here" />
```

I'm hoping to expand this idea to numerous controls that have the flexibility to handle numerous attributes. The end result would be to take a collection of objects and to generate either a .ascx or .aspx based upon the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Placeholder, you could then add as many controls to it as you'd like.

```
    Dim lblTest As New Label
    lblTest.ID = "lblTest"
    lblTest.Text = "Text Here"
    lblTest.CssClass = "myClass"
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(lblTest)
```

Comment: Then how can I get the Placeholder to generate the asp code? I can get it to generate HTML, just not ASP.